# MYSQL - QUERY FROM TWO TABLES

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Question - let's say I have 2 tables.

Table 1 - name is permission_list, columns are ID (unique ID), col_ID, user_ID

Table 2 - name is list_entries, Columns are ID (unique ID), title, description, status

I want to select all the rows from table 2 that have status of 'public' as well as all the rows from table 2 that the ID from table 2 shows up in table 1 (under the column col_ID) AND if the user_ID in table 1 matches a certain value. So, anything public, or anything that this specific user has listed under the permissions table. This query would also remove duplicates - in case the user gets a public entry listed in their permissions_list, it wouldn't show up twice.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Sample code : `SELECT table1.* , table2.* FROM table1 , table2 WHERE table1.id=3490 AND table2.value>500`

Comment: Or, the more readable JOIN...
SELECT table1.* , table2.* 
FROM table1
join table2 ON table1.id=3490 AND table2.value>500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.* from table2
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (id)
WHERE status='public'
OR user_ID='someuser';
```

Comment: Not gonna help them learn. How many questions like this do you want to see on here?

Comment: I'm naive - They wouldn't ask here if they'd know what to search for.

Comment: This one effectively answers the question. I'm not new to mysql, but I couldn't figure out from my googling if this sort of a query would eliminate entries listed from table2 if they didn't show up in table1.

However, it didn't occur to me that by default, entries in table1 are either duplicates of entries that should show up from table2 regardless, or are not public and therefor don't need to be 'eliminated'. So really, it's just 'all public, or all the ones that correspond to another table'. Brainfart on my part - but thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Plus, bonus points on USING - I didn't know of that one. I knew 'ON', 'USING' just seems more elegant.

Comment: Why couldn't you describe the issue with that much detail in the original question? There is nothing wrong with a lot of words. You're looking at the difference between inner and outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some education on JOIN for your first thing, and the second thing is called DISTINCT.

Start here... https://www.google.com/

You have not specified your join condition so we can't give you code samples really. Also the way you worded your question, I'm not entirely sure you don't want a UNION. Read up on those concepts and come back here when you can improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_2.status, table_2.ID, table_1.col_ID
FROM table_1 JOIN table_2
WHERE table_2.status = 'public'
    AND table_2.ID = table_1.col_ID
    AND table_1.user_ID = 'certain value'
    ;
```

Try this